# c# Can I prevent my constructor arguments clashing with VBA instantiation?

Tags: c#, vba

I'm a bit confused about how I can override constructors requiring arguments when using their classes in a VBA environment.

**What works?**

I've created several classes in a library, each with an interface to allow full intellisense compatibility when using this library in VBA

With or without constructors, these classes work fine for me e.g.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("JamHeadArt.ClassEX")]
[Guid("XYZ")]
public partial class ClassEX : IClassEX
{

    public ClassEX()
    {
        // Empty constructor here, some of mine have processes, all work well
    }  

    // Methods/ Properties as outlined by the interface below
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("ABC")]
public interface IClassEx
{
    // Various methods / fields / properties to be implemented by ClassEX
}
```

I then add reference to my library and write simple lines of code in VBA to instantiate and access my classes:

```
Sub Test()
Dim t As JamHeadArt.ClassEX
Set t = New JamHeadArt.ClassEX
' Using t.dot then provides all the methods needed '
End Sub
```

**What goes wrong?**

When I create contstructors with arguments (even if optional) in a class, VBA will stop allowing me to create instances of these classes, it tells me the "New" keyword is Invalid and actually won't allow me to choose the class from the intellisense list of objects in my library if I go straight for `Dim t As New JamHeadArt.ClassEx` even if the parameters are set to optional (therefore not really needed)

The annoying thing here is - I don't actually **want** my VBA instances to accept parameters via the constructor, they're mainly there for Unit testing and they're optional strings so default to "" ... so I guess my question is something like

**Is it possible to override any constructor parameters so when referenced in a VBA environment it will ignore them?**

e.g. I really want my constructor to look like this:

```
public ClassEX(string s = "")
{

}
```

and in VBA it should work as before `Dim t As New JamHeadArt.ClassEX` - but it won't with that optional string in there!

Comment: Can't you just add an additional constructor? i.e.: one paremeterless, the other one with parameters for unit testing

Comment: I have not worked with VBA but in c# you can have an `internal` constructor and a `public` constructor. The internal one can be for unit testing and the public one for VBA. Use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` so only the unit testing app can see that constructor. That's a possible solution but I do not like writing code just for unit testing. Mostly this is a design flaw but sometimes there is no other way. Hard to say since I have limited info about your case but at least that is one solution.

Comment: @Stefan I hadn't tried that - I think I was so preoccupied with the fact the parameter is optional in the first place but give me five and I'll see if that works

Comment: @CodingYoshi That sounds like a great solution if works - and yes the code is quite poorly set out, some idiot (me about a year ago) wrote all this hideous stuff and this optional parameter was the least convoluted way of implementing unit testing.

Comment: @Stefan - that worked. Honestly, can't see the wood for the trees sometimes. So simple and look how much crap I had to write out in my question!!! All because I was focussing on "optional" parameters... it means I have to WET a little bit of my code but thank you!

Comment: Please do, I'll mark up ASAP

Comment: Do the workbook have any vba code in the THISWORKBOOK?  Excel automatically executes THISWORKBOOK and cannot be overridden.  The class constructors may be executed from THISWORKBOOK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional constructor, for example:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("JamHeadArt.ClassEX")]
[Guid("XYZ")]
public partial class ClassEX : IClassEX
{
    public ClassEX()
    {
        // Empty constructor here, some of mine have processes, all work well
    }  

    public ClassEX(string foo)
    {
        // additional constructor, can be used for unit testing etc.
    }  

    // Methods/ Properties as outlined by the interface below
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this is the best solution for me - it's not ideal because I have to basically copy and paste everything from one to the other but that's due to poor code-writing setting up a bad framework a while ago in the first place!